# Recording phone calls

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am working on Windows Phone 7 development, which I am currently learning at the university.
So as a course project, I am working on a project which works on phone calls. I have a few questions in mind in order to decide whether this project is implementable or not.

Firstly, is it possible to make my application record a conversation (i.e. the phone call)?
Secondly, is it possible to launch the recording application automatically when someone calls, or would I have to launch it manually?

Comment: There is at least one [existing app in the marketplace](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-GB/apps/0ae54c27-41f6-43eb-8b91-61a7f95e01a3)

Answer (score 2):

First of all you would have to launch it manually, second of all I highly doubt that this is possible for a variety of reasons: for example, the privacy of your phone buddy or prevention of virus access.

Therefore I would say that it isn't possible to record incoming calls; there might be a possibility with outgoing calls, since you can call through your app.

Well, you could run the microphone and record everything but: (a) this would only work when talking via speaker, and (b) the quality would be so crappy I think you wouldn't be happy.

Comment: thanks .. things are clear now, but one last thing is if it's possible to play a sound file to the caller from the phone itself ?

Comment: since there now is multitasking available you could play a sound trough the speakers which the caller would hear when you are calling via speaker

Comment: @user721717 this will help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

aswell asthis: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.phonecalltask%28v=vs.92%29

there should be all information regarding calls in there. regards Master117

Comment: @user721717 would you be so kind as to mark my answer correct?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot record a phone call and you cannot play sound files back to a caller on Windows Phone 7.

Regards,
Paul